# Insert images in E-Mail Newsletter

Tags: html, image, email, newsletter

Can someone tell me how i can create an HTML Newsletter with images?

I used the img src tag like this

```
<img src="http://abload.de/img/dfdfb.png" width="234px" height="34px">
```

but if i **send the mail from outlook** and open the mail in **thunderbird**, *there is no image.*

If i send the same html newsletter from **Thunderbird** and open it in **outlook**, the picture is *available*.

This Question: [how to send image in newsletter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131815/how-to-send-image-in-newsletter) doesn't helped!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Take a look at your link.  I just visted your src link..I got a 404.

Comment: this is only an example link :-)

Answer (score 0):

To send html straight from Outlook, put your html in a webpage (or the render preview of your text editor) and copy the rendered result into your email body. Using html code typed into Outlook by itself (even set to the HTML option) will not render.

In your simple case, save your image tag code as a html file, open that file in a browser. Should be a white page with just your image on it. Drag over the image within the browser and copy paste it into your email body.